# kfold validation error - ValueError: bad input shape (513, 10)

Tags: python, pandas, validation, machine-learning

Kfold commands for accuracy, AUC and recall worked fine but now showing errors.

kernel restarted a number of times and attempted alternative approaches to no avail, such as 'stratifiedkfold', 'in emumerate' and looping.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
svc_clf = svm.SVC(C=50, 
                  kernel='rbf', 
                  gamma=0.1,
                  probability=False,
                  class_weight={1: 5}
                 )
svc_clf.fit(X_train_std, y_train)

# K-fold cross-validator
kfold = Kfold(n_splits=10, random_state=140311, shuffle=True)
for train_index, test_index in kfold.split(X):
    X_training, X_testing = X_train_std[train_index], X_train_std[test_index]
    y_training, y_testing = y_train[train_index], y_train[test_index]

df_kfold_acc = cross_val_score(svc_clf, X_train_std, y_train, cv=kfold, scoring='accuracy')
print'10 fold validation accuracy scores: \n', (df_kfold_acc)
print'Kfold mean accuracy score: \n', (df_kfold_acc).mean()

df_kfold_auc = cross_val_score(svc_clf, X_train_std, y_train, cv=kfold, scoring='roc_auc')
print'\n\n 10 fold validation AUC scores:\n ', (df_kfold_auc)
print'Kfold mean AUC score: \n', (df_kfold_auc).mean()

df_kfold_recall = cross_val_score(svc_clf, X_train_std, y_train, cv=kfold, scoring='recall')
print'\n\n 10 fold validation recall scores:\n', (df_kfold_recall)
print'Kfold mean recall score: \n', (df_kfold_recall).mean()
```

Expected (and previous got) something like the following:

10 fold validation accuracy scores: {0.7982993, 0.6793838, etc (for 10 folds total)}
Kfold mean accuracy score: 0.78679979

Actual error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-56-61c6420c7a2f> in <module>()
      6                   class_weight={1: 5}
      7                  )
----> 8 svc_clf.fit(X_train_std, y_train)
      9 
     10 # K-fold cross-validator

/Users/db/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/svm/base.pyc in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight)
    147         self._sparse = sparse and not callable(self.kernel)
    148 
--> 149         X, y = check_X_y(X, y, dtype=np.float64, order='C', accept_sparse='csr')
    150         y = self._validate_targets(y)
    151 

/Users/db/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.pyc in check_X_y(X, y, accept_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, multi_output, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, y_numeric, warn_on_dtype, estimator)
    576                         dtype=None)
    577     else:
--> 578         y = column_or_1d(y, warn=True)
    579         _assert_all_finite(y)
    580     if y_numeric and y.dtype.kind == 'O':

/Users/db/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.pyc in column_or_1d(y, warn)
    612         return np.ravel(y)
    613 
--> 614     raise ValueError("bad input shape {0}".format(shape))
    615 
    616 

ValueError: bad input shape (513, 10)
```

Comment: The error alternates between that mentioned in the description above and the following error: NameError: name 'Kfold' is not defined

Answer (score 0):

The error warns you about the shape of the data you are passing for training is not in the correct shape.
x_train : Training vector {array-like, sparse matrix}, shape (n_samples, n_features)
y : Target vector relative to X array-like, shape (n_samples,).

Since you gave no information about the data you are using, (513,10) shape for X is okay, but you should check the target vector shape. It should be the shape mentioned above.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold,cross_val_score
from sklearn import svm

X_train = np.array([[1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,1],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]])
y_train = np.array([1,1,0,0])

svc_clf = svm.SVC(C=50, 
                  kernel='rbf', 
                  gamma=0.1,
                  probability=False,
                  class_weight={1: 5}
                 )

# K-fold cross-validator
kfold = KFold(n_splits=4, random_state=140311, shuffle=True)

df_kfold_acc = cross_val_score(svc_clf, X_train, y_train, cv=kfold, scoring='accuracy')
print('4 fold validation accuracy scores: \n', (df_kfold_acc))
print('Kfold mean accuracy score: \n', (df_kfold_acc).mean())
```

Output :

```
4 fold validation accuracy scores: 
 [1. 1. 1. 1.]
Kfold mean accuracy score: 
 1.0
```

Comment: 570 for the class label (target), which is the same number as for the feature space as a whole before splitting.  After splitting the training set is 456 and the testing set is 114.

Comment: Actually it throws error when you want to fit your classifier, so something must be with the data your are passing. Maybe if you would give some info what it contains then i can help. By the way you get the NameError because you instantiated a KFold as Kfold,

Comment: I altered the name kfold to k_fold  and to fold with the same error.  Recoded the following: X = X_train_std and y = y_train, which resulted in the error: TypeError: 'KFold' object is not iterable .

Comment: The data itself is from the indian liver dataset from the UCL machine learning website.

Comment: Btw your code is a bit messed up. The for cycle does nothing actually, also you dont need to fit your estimator (SVC). I think deleting this two and changing your `kfold = Kfold(n_splits=10, random_state=140311, shuffle=True)` to `kfold = KFold(n_splits=10, random_state=140311, shuffle=True)` gonna solve the issue.

Comment: Attempting support vector classifier and a random forrest classifier.  F1, AUC, confusion matrix, precision and recall.  All worked fine earlier today.

Comment: No joy, gives the following:TypeError: 'KFold' object is not iterable .  Earlier I had the script the way you outlined, but the 'iterable' error showed up and hence the estimator fit and the for command.  Kfold is now KFold.

Comment: Well, i just tested and it works for me. Gonna edit above code, maybe it can help.

Comment: I tried the following and it seems to work (for now):

Comment: from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
~~~
X = X_train_std
y = y_train  
# K-fold cross-validator
k_fold = KFold(random_state=140311, n_splits=10, shuffle=True)
k_fold_sp = k_fold.split(X, y)~~~

Comment: The key addition is the k_fold_sp = k_fold.split(X, y)

Comment: it was a team effort.